# Upload base64 image to amazon s3

Tags: php, image, amazon-s3, upload, base64

I'm having some issues when trying to upload an image to AWS S3. It seems to upload the file correctly but, whenever I try to download or preview, it can't be opened. Currently, this is the upload code I'm using:

```
<?php
require_once 'classes/amazon.php';
require_once 'includes/aws/aws-autoloader.php';
use Aws\S3\S3Client;

$putdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($putdata);

$image_parts = explode(";base64,", $request->image);
$image_type_aux = explode("image/", $image_parts[0]);
$image_type = $image_type_aux[1];
$image_base64 = $image_parts[1];

$dateTime = new DateTime();
$fileName = $dateTime->getTimestamp() . "." . $image_type;  

$s3Client = S3Client::factory(array(
    'region' => 'eu-west-1',
    'version' => '2006-03-01',
    'credentials' => array(
        'key'    => Amazon::getAccessKey(),
        'secret' => Amazon::getSecretKey(),
    )
));

try {
    $result = $s3Client->putObject(array(
        'Bucket'          => Amazon::getBucket(),
        'Key'             => 'banners/' . $fileName,
        'Body'            => $image_base64,
        'ContentType'     => 'image/' . $image_type,
        'ACL'             => 'public-read'
    ));
    echo $result['ObjectURL'] . "\n";
} catch(S3Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}
?>
```

So, when I check the console after uploading the image file, it has the expected size, permissions and headers but, as I said, whenever I try to open the file, it fails.

What could be the problem here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue here is you appear to be uploading the base64 encoded version of the image and not the raw bytes of the image. Take $image_base64 and decode into raw bytes first http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php . I am sure if you tried to open those "images" in a text editor you would see base64 hex data.

Answer (score 4):

you can upload "on the fly" by using the function **$s3Client->upload** like the following example:

```
<?php
$bucket = 'bucket-name';
$filename = 'image-path.extension';
$imageData = base64_decode(end(explode(",", $base64)));
$upload = $s3Client->upload($bucket, $filename, $imageData, 'public-read');
$upload->get('ObjectURL');
```

Answer (score 1):

I use silex php 2.0  and the following code fount

```
    $s3 = $app['aws']->createS3();
    $putdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
    $data = (object) $data;
    $image_parts = explode(";base64,", $data->image);
    $image_type_aux = explode("image/", $image_parts[0]);
    $image_type = $image_type_aux[1];
    $image_base64 = base64_decode($image_parts[1]);
    $result = $s3->putObject([
        'ACL' => 'public-read',
        'Body' => $image_base64,
        'Bucket' => 'name-bucket',
        'Key' => 'test_img.jpeg',
        'ContentType' => 'image/' . $image_type,
    ]);
    var_dump($result['ObjectURL']);
```

Comment: Hi oldwil19, what's "fount"?